# How to create dynamic linq with EF.Function.FreeText

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I try to create dynamic LINQ with FreeText

```
var method= typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions).GetMethod("FreeText", new[] { typeof(DbFunctions), typeof(string), typeof(string) });

var expression = Expression.Call(null, likeMethod, Expression.Constant(EF.Functions), memberExpression, Expression.Constant($"{value}"));
```

but `method` is null. Anyone help me.

Thanks

Comment: Method FreeText is defined in SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions, not in DbFunctionsExtensions

Comment: Thank you @pakeha. Now it work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`FreeText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.freetext?view=efcore-3.1) function is defined in the [`SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions?view=efcore-3.1) class, *not* in `DbFunctionsExtensions`.

```
var memberExpression = GetMemberExpression();
var method = typeof(SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions).GetMethod("FreeText", new[] { typeof(DbFunctions), typeof(string), typeof(string) });
var freeTextCall = Expression.Call(
   null, 
   method, 
   Expression.Constant(EF.Functions), 
   memberExpression, 
   Expression.Constant($"{value}")
);
```